# Referring to a sandbox file from HTML with iPhone

Tags: iphone, html, uiwebview, nsdata

I'm trying to build a HTML based application for the iPad.  I want to build a background process using Objective-C to download images and data and then refer to those from within a HTML file using the UIWebView.

I can successfully download an image and save it to the Documents sandbox directory.  In the simulator I can see the path, but that's on my machine, not on the iPhone sandbox.  Is there a shortcode for referencing the documents directory?

I want to do something like

```
~/Documents/image.png
```

Thanks

Robbie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the Documents directory I use

```
NSArray *documents = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
```

Comment: Yeah, I can get that, but I'd like to know if there's a way of getting  to that file from a HTML img src attribute within the UIWebView. I don't think I can pass that into the UIWebView instance to use within the javascript code I'm using.

Comment: Pass strings to javascript using stringByEvalutaingJavascriptFromString

Comment: Then I don't have any other solution then drawnonward.

Comment: OK, I'm getting somewhere using stringByEvalutaingJavascriptFromString. I can do something like an alert, but nothing seems to be happening when I'm calling a function that should be available.  I'm waiting for the delegate webViewDidLoad callback before executing this.  Can I call functions that should be in scope?

Comment: Ah ok, it depends on the scope of the Javascript.  Had to get a function defined as:

function myFunc(){...} instead of myFunc = function(){...}

All working,thanks